# AngularJS: Hide element on scroll with $animate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, directive

I have the following directive:

```
angular.module('mymod').directive("hideOnScroll", function($animate, $document) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $document.bind('scroll', function () {
            if ($document.scrollTop() > 80) {
                console.log("this is fired1")
                $animate.addClass(element, "fade");
            } else {
                console.log("this is fired2")
                $animate.removeClass(element, "fade");
            }
        });
    };
});
```

I have both "this is fired" messages in the log at some point

Plus, I have the following animation service:

```
angular.module('mymod').animation(".fade", function() {
    console.log("this is never fired3")

    return {
        addClass: function(element, className) {
            console.log("this is never fired4")
            //TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity: 0});
        },
        removeClass: function(element, className) {
            console.log("this is never fired5")
            //TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity: 1});
        }
    };
});
```

None of it's console messages is fired. at all (3, 4 and 5). I checked if it's added to the browser, it is. And I have ngAnimate as a dependency

This is the element:

```
<div hide-on-scroll>Hello</div>
```

Edit: I can see in chrome's element inspector that the div doesn't get the new class after '$animate.addClass(element, "fade")' is fired

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When event handlers attached manually by for example `addEventListener()` or by the jqLite/jQuery methods `on`and `bind` execute you need to manually trigger the digest loop to let Angular know that something has changed.

You can use `$apply` (like for example `ng-click` does internally):

```
$document.bind('scroll', function() {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    if ($document.scrollTop() > 80) {
      console.log("this is fired1");
      $animate.addClass(element, "fade");
    } else {
      console.log("this is fired2");
      $animate.removeClass(element, "fade");
    }
  });
});
```

Also note that when you attach event listeners to the document you should manually remove them when the scope is destroyed:

```
var onScroll = function() {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    if ($document.scrollTop() > 80) {
      console.log("this is fired1");
      $animate.addClass(element, "fade");
    } else {
      console.log("this is fired2");
      $animate.removeClass(element, "fade");
    }
  });
};

$document.bind('scroll', onScroll);

scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  $document.unbind('scroll', onScroll);
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/wl0vujSnBcb24FHGQ4il?p=preview